# How to animate a histogram from a list of lists

Tags: matplotlib, animation, histogram

I have a list of lists of auction returns. Each list can be summarized by a histogram. I would like to animate this histogram to show for each list.

I have tried funcanimation but I'm unable to understand much of the documentation. Similarly I have tried to use code from similar stack overflow questions and I am unable to animate my plt.hist

```
#Attempt 1
a = [4,3,1,7,9,5,3,4,6,0,3,1,4,5,4,6,0]
b = [9,4,5,1,6,5,3,4,0,6,7,3,4,7,6,3,7]
c = [4,3,1,7,9,5,3,4,6,0,3,1,4,5,4,6,0]
d = [9,4,5,1,6,5,3,4,0,6,7,3,4,7,6,3,7]
e = [4,3,1,7,9,5,3,4,6,0,3,1,4,5,4,6,0]
data = [a,b,c,d,e]

number_of_frames = 5
def update_hist(num, data):
    plt.cla()
    plt.hist(data[num])

fig = plt.figure()
hist = plt.hist(data[0])

animation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_hist,   number_of_frames, fargs=(data, ), interval = 2000 )
plt.show()

#Attempt 2
fig = plt.figure()
#creating a subplot 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    ax1.clear()
    plt.hist(data[i])
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.xlabel('Percentage Return')
    plt.title('Auction Histograph') 


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=5000) 
plt.show()
```

Both of these attempts show the first histogram, but it never transitions to the second.

Comment: Both codes are correct and do work as expected. You may have a problem with *how* you run the code; but there is no information about that in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I've added %matplotlib notebook and that has helped somewhat. I'm getting animation now, but it is only showing one bin in the histogram at a time rather than all of them

Comment: I don't understand "one bin in the histogram at a time".